# why providerRoute is not working

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

```
    var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/Home", {
            templateUrl: "Home/EmployeeList",
            controller: "listController",
        })
        .when("/Home1", {
            templateUrl: "Home/EmployeeTable",
            controller: "tableController",
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: "/Home/Index"
        })
        .controller("listController", function ($scope) {
            $scope.message = "In list controller";
        })
});
```

why on running code TypeError:routeProvider.when(...).when(...).otherwise(...).controller error shows in cosole.

Comment: Please provide the full error details.

Comment: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$injector/modulerr?p0=MyApp&p1=TypeError%3A%20%24routeProvider.when(...).when(...).3)
    at angular.js:38
    at angular.js:4920
    at q (angular.js:403)
    at g (angular.js:4880)
    at eb (angular.js:4802)
    at c (angular.js:1914)
    at Sc (angular.js:1935)
    at ue (angular.js:1820)
    at angular.js:33367
    at HTMLDocument.b (angular.js:3431)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the controller registration call out of the config block. There is no `$routeProvider.controller`

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/Home", {
            templateUrl: "Home/EmployeeList",
            controller: "listController",
        })
        .when("/Home1", {
            templateUrl: "Home/EmployeeTable",
            controller: "tableController",
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: "/Home/Index"
        })

});


app.controller("listController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = "In list controller";
})
```